# OBIEE connect to impala

Tags: odbc, cloudera, obiee, impala

I'm trying to connect OBIEE to Impala. Where I try my test, I encounter a problem that I can't
resolved,here comes my steps:

1. download the Cloudera latest Impala ODBC driver for windows,and import metadata from impala,I can finally successfully see data in Admin Tools like this:
   [image]
2. upload the rpd file to the server,and download cloudera impala odbc driver for linux,and configure it,in the end ,I can  do it like this which shows I have configure the driver successfully:
   [image]
3. I try to create new analysis through 【Create Direct Database Request】 to test weather I can successfully connect Impala, but I can never connect it due to the reason like this,I can never fingure out why:
   [image]

Is there anybody successfully do it or tell me how I can resolve the problem? Thanks!

Comment: I can't read error text on second screenshot. Can you copy-paste it as text? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recommend connecting directly to Hive instead. According to Oracle's documentation Impala connectivity is not directly supported. OBIEE is built connect to Hive and Impala is not referenced:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e10540/deploy_rpd.htm#BABGIAJH

Comment: We work with Impala from OBIEE just fine. Latest version of OBIEE do support Impala. I'd recommend to use Cloudera drivers though and not default data direct. DD drivers lack support of some more recent data types, and it seems lacks support of Kerberos authentication too. Thanls.